# Can't upload Android APK to Google play store using Fastlane

Tags: android, google-play, fastlane

I installed the Fastlane and updated the FastFile according to the steps provided [here](https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/android/setup/) and then uploaded my first APK on the google play console using Fastlane.

But while executing the command below it gives an error.

> command: fastlane supply init
>     error: "No application was found for the given package name."

Answer (score 9):

See similar issue [here](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/3628).
You have to create the application and upload at least one APK through the Play Console before making any modifications using Fastlane.

Quoting [this response](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/3628#issuecomment-194089078):

> `supply` will upload new metadata for an app (or a new apk for an
>   existing app), but cannot upload a brand new app due to Google API
>   limitations.